# get path of pom, sources, and javadoc jar

Tags: gradle

I have been hacking away at this all evening and im close, im really close to making this work.  Im so excited.  I only have one major hurdle and a question.

First, the question.  I figured out how to control the download of pom files, artifacts, and jars with the configuration object thru what i'm assuming is the dependency resolution engine.  But I noticed a discrepancy.  For the class im testing with, when I kick off the dependency resolver, it downloads 39 pom files.  But, when i look at my artifacts object under the configuration object, it only lists 25 objects.  when i dump the classpath to a folder, i get 25 libraries, but when I do a project report, It lists 32 libraries.  Are these count discrepancies normal?  Is it normal for gradle to download a pom file and realize it didn't need the artifact?

Now my issue, I have the thing giving me the full path of the jar files in the classpath with this

```
def artifacts = configurations.compile.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts as List
```

now the problem is I need the full paths of the POM, sources, and javadoc jars as well so I can turn them around and install them into the internal artifactory server.

How do i get those paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get the path to the sources and javadoc jar if you add a dependency on that classifier. For example:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12:
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12:sources'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12:javadoc'
}

configurations.testCompile.each {
    println it
}
```

As far as I know there is currently no way to get the path to the pom.xml via Gradle. But once you have the path to the main jar it should not be a problem to search for the corresponding pom.xml.

In this example the pom.xml would be located somewhere in
    `$GRADLE_HOME/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/<some-hash>/junit-4.12.pom`